# Error when trying to create a multi-layer neural network for two-class classification

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm currently trying to create a two layer neural network using the following Net# code:

```
input Data auto;
hidden H1 1600 from Data all;
hidden H2 1600 from H1 all;
output Result auto from H2;
```

For some reason when I run the experiment, I get this error:

```
requestId = cbc3ec794f0a48799b66f8a53b6cc1f3 errorComponent=Module. taskStatusCode=400. {
    "Exception":{            
        "ErrorId":"LibraryException",
        "ErrorCode":"1000",
        "ExceptionType":"ModuleException",
        "Message":"Error 1000: TLC library exception: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Numerics.AFxLibraryException' was thrown.",
        "Exception":{
            "Library":"TLC",
            "ExceptionType":"LibraryException",
            "Message":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.Numerics.AFxLibraryException' was thrown."
        }
    }
}
Error: Error 1000: TLC library exception: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Numerics.AFxLibraryException' was thrown. Process exited with error code -2
```

I don't get this error when I use the normal single layer builder interface that is initially presented. Any help would be much appreciated in diagnosing this.

Comment: I believe you have a problem with your incoming data. I have setup something similar with no issues. Edit: You are missing all at the end of the last line. "output Result auto from H2 all;"

Comment: I have the same issue and I am using the "all" clause.